# not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0)

Tags: python

I have the following error:

> not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0)

Please help.

Here is my code:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    ## Initialize the variables
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    for epoch in range(training_epochs):           
        for batch in total_batch:
            batch_images, batch_labels = map(list, zip(*batch))
            batch_images = np.array(batch_images)
            batch_labels = np.array(batch_labels).reshape(-1, 1)

            ## Run the training procedures
            _, l, acc = sess.run([optimizer, loss, accuracy], feed_dict={x: batch_images, y: 
            batch_labels})

        if epoch % display == 0:
            print('\nEpoch: %d, Loss: %f, Accuracy: %f' % (epoch + 1, l, acc))
```

Comment: Please specify which line you get this error

Comment: Do you have any empty ``batch``?

Answer (score -1):

I believe this is due to the use of `map`. You sould convert the result into an iterable, like a `list` or a `tuple`. Try changing this line of code:

```
...
for batch in total_batch:
    batch_images, batch_labels = list(map(list, zip(*batch)))
...
```

Comment: ``map`` *is* an iterable.